# PHP: MySql Update Statement by displaying information first

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update info from mysql database through displaying it first. I used textarea to display the information to be updated from database.

viewUpdate.php

```
 <?php
   $host="localhost";
   $user_name="root";
   $database_name="5r";
   $db=mysql_connect($host, $user_name,'');
   if (mysql_error() > "") echo mysql_error() . "<br>";
   mysql_select_db($database_name, $db);
   if (mysql_error() > "") echo mysql_error() . "<br>";
   $query = "SELECT * FROM tblMain WHERE No=1";
   $result = mysql_query($query);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
            echo '<form method="post" action="updateMain.php">
                <table border=0>
                <tr>
                   <td><font face="Times New Roman" color="463D01" size=3> Title: <br>
                       <textarea rows=2 cols=30 name="s1" id="s1">'.$row["title"].'</textarea></font><br>
                        <font face="Times New Roman" color="463D01" size=3> Information: <br>
                        <textarea rows=5 cols=30 name="s2" id="s2">'.$row["info"].'</textarea></font><br><br>
                 </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary"> &nbsp &nbsp
                    </form><a href="admin1.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button></a>

                </tr>
            </table>';
```

Aside from `<textarea>`, how can I used the `<input type="text">` to display a short detail to be updated?

Comment: `<input type="text" value="$row[text_to_display]" />`?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't worked. :(

Comment: doesn't work **HOW**? no input field is output? the page is corrupted?

Comment: that should work. Anyway, you have some invalid HTML in your code. Add names to your inputs, close them with `/` character, Put `form` tag outside of the `table`, and move `button` to inside of your `form`.

Comment: Okey, I'll try again. Thanks Guys. :)